# localhost name resolution suddenly stopped working for subdomains

Tags: macos, curl, dns, localhost

Yesterday I was working away happily, on my Mac (OS v10.15.7), having just setup a project that uses domain & sub-domain names to identify the tenants of a system, and everything was working fine.  I could go to http://hello.my-domain.localhost:8888 and it would resolve just fine.

This morning I've come to work on this again however my curl requests are now, suddenly reporting "Could not resolve host: hello.my-domain.localhost", where they were working just fine yesterday.

If I visit this in the (Brave) browser it works just fine.

If I curl http://hello.localhost:8888 it works just fine.

I really would like to know why curl has suddenly changed how it resolves hostnames?!

I have tried `dscacheutil -flushcache` both with & without sudo, and also tried rebooting, but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot that now I'm on Catalina I need to run `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` rather than using `dscacheutil -flushcache` (even though that command also exists!

Have now run `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` and everything's working again.

Not sure how I forgot this, since I have to do this regularly since upgrading to Catalina, for some annoying reason.